# d3.js: chronological time view

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can i render bar graphs on x axes, relative to time.

For e.g:

Views on my Web :  10, 20,   30,  60
Period          : Jan, Feb, Jun, Dec

the x axes should display first 2 columns closed to each other, with a relative gap then to June, and then again a bigger gap to Dec.

Comment: Just like you usally have something like `d3.scale.linear()` for your Y axis, you need to have another one for your X axis. It would either be also a linear scale, or perhaps a `d3.time.scale()`. Really though, you should try some stuff on your own and post a jsFiddle showing progress –– before asking vague questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as each data item can be represented on the same scale you could do something like the below.  For example, if your first values are hours, and the next set are months, you could just make everything relative to hours.

given: 1 month = 744 hours

use x values:
10, 20, 30, 60, 744, 1488, 4464, 8928